# Improve performance when update objects in array with External Data input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I need to update specific objects in array. There is an external data input(array of objects)with the same key but different values. I need to update the old array with new array based on keys. Currently I use four for-loops to update the array. The performance is bad if oldData[] has 200+ items and newData[] has 100+ items. I'm wondering if there is any better way to do this.

I have below code as an example:

```
/* Object structure needs to stay the same*/
    var oldData = [
      {
        "10001":{
          name : 'Bill\'s Truck',
          type : 'Truck',
          speed: 50,
          string: 'This is a huge string I also need to update'
        }      
      },
      {
        "56781":{
          name : 'Jay\'s Van',
          type : 'Van',
          speed: 60,
          string: 'This is a huge string I also need to update'
        }      
      }
    ];
    $scope.oldData= oldData;

    /*This data is actually from external API*/
    var newData = [
      {
        "10001":{
          name : 'Bill\'s Truck',
          type : 'Truck',
          speed: 80
        }      
      }
    ];

    /*Is there any better way to do this?*/
    for(var old_index in oldData){
      var old_device = oldData[old_index];
      for(var old_deviceID in old_device){
        for(var new_index in newData){
           var new_device = newData[new_index];
           for(var new_deviceID in new_device){
              if(old_deviceID === new_deviceID){
                 console.log('Gotcha' + old_deviceID);
                 oldData[old_index] = angular.copy(new_device);
              }
           }
        }
      }      
    }
```

A working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11253/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve it by using:

1. `Object.keys` to simplify the inner loops.
2. Access the needed property (given that you need to update `speed` only here) instead of looping through all the properties - you can do away with copying whole objects using `angular.copy`.

Demo below:

```js
var oldData=[{10001:{name:"Bill's Truck",type:"Truck",speed:50,string:"This is a huge string I also need to update"}},{56781:{name:"Jay's Van",type:"Van",speed:60,string:"This is a huge string I also need to update"}}];
var newData=[{10001:{name:"Bill Dodge Ram",type:"Truck",speed:80}}];

oldData.forEach(function(element) {
  if (Object.keys(element)[0] === Object.keys(this[0])[0]) {
    element[Object.keys(element)[0]].speed = this[0][Object.keys(this[0])[0]].speed;
  }
}, newData);

console.log(oldData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.merge(oldData, newData)` which is a built in angular method to merge objects as it's described on [Angularjs docs for `angular.merge`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend). Also, there is [`angular.extends`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) which merge only object's first level without going recursively deep as `angular.merge` does.